# Fetch limited number documents of same key with single request

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the below model in mongodb. The database has about 1000 records and I want to fetch only 10 documents for every different storeName with a single request if it is possible. I do not want to make request for every storeName. For example storeName1 = Offers.find({storeName: "storeName1"}).limit(10), storeName2 = Offers.find({storeName: "storeName2"}).limit(10)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const offersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    imgLink: String,
    title: String,
    startPrice: Number,
    discountPrice: Number,
    pageLink: String,
    storeName: String,
    offerType: String,
    discountPercentage: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Offers", offersSchema);
```